# Can this condition be proved in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have a sequence of integers having a total sum greater than or equal to 0. We have to find the sum of the integers of the sequence from an index in a cyclic manner until we reach the start index.
Eg. the sequence = {1, 2, -2, -1, 5}, if we start from the 3rd index and find the sum (initially 0), then

*index 3* : sum = -2

*index 4* : sum = -2 -1 = -3

*index 5* : sum = -3 + 5 = 2

*index 1* : sum = 2 + 1 = 3

*index 2* : sum = 3 + 2 = 5

Hence, we get the sum in the following sequence if we start from 3rd index: {-2, -3, 2, 3, 5}. Is it possible to prove that if the total sum of the sequence is non-negative, there will always exist such an index from which the sum will never be less than 0? For example, in this case, if we start from the 5th index, we get sum values as {5, 6, 8, 6, 5} which never goes less than 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is always a place in the sequence such that, if you start your summation there, you never get a negative sum. To find it, first, as a preliminary step, do the summation starting anywhere you like. Of course, this might go negative as in your example. If it doesn't go negative, you've got what you want. If it does go negative, find the most negative of these partial  sums. (In your example, that would be the $-3$.) The next summand after that partial sum (in your example it's $5$) is the place you want to start.

The reason this works is that, by starting after the most negative partial sum, say $-m$, you'll get new partial sums that begin with $0$ where you previously had $-m$. So as you go around the cycle, all your new partial sums will be larger by at least $m$ than the partial sum that you originally had up to the same point. Since $-m$ was the most negative original partial sum, all the others are $\geq-m$, and so the new partial sums, being bigger by at least $m$, will all be $\geq0$.